# Load XML file, replace all "X" with "Y" and carry on using file

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

This is the code:

```
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($candidateFile);

        if (!$xml) {
            $this->addCritical("ERROR: " . basename($candidateFile));
            return;
        }

        $ModifiedXml = simplexml_load_string( str_replace( "\n</DESIGNATION_PLU>", '</DESIGNATION_PLU>', $xml ) );
```

The last line does not work, all that I need is that it will use loaded XML "$xml" replace some of the things and carry on working by using modified XML.

If I'm not clear, or you will need more information, just let me know.

Bigger section of code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($candidateFile);

if (!$xml) {
    $this->addCritical("ERROR: " . basename($candidateFile));
    return;
}

// Before it will write to the new files I need to fix original XML 

$candidateFilenameParts = explode('_', basename($candidateFile));
$candidateFileDatetime = str_replace('.xml', '', $candidateFilenameParts[3]);

$headerFilename = "header_$candidateFileDatetime.csv";
$productFilename = "product_$candidateFileDatetime.csv";
$paymentFilename = "payment_$candidateFileDatetime.csv";
$this->addInfo("");
```

XML: It looks like initially, values in XML had endings like "\n"

```
                <LIGNE>
                    <ID_TICKET>123</ID_TICKET>
                    <CODE_RAYON>123</CODE_RAYON>
                    <CODE_VENDEUR>123</CODE_VENDEUR>
                    <PLU>123</PLU>
                    <DESIGNATION_PLU>New 1234      
    ---> Next line  </DESIGNATION_PLU>
                    <CODE_EAN/>
                    <TYPE_ARTICLE>Pièce</TYPE_ARTICLE>
                    <QUANTITE_VENDUE>1</QUANTITE_VENDUE>
                    <UNITE_MESURE>123</UNITE_MESURE>
                    <PRIX_UNITAIRE_TTC>123</PRIX_UNITAIRE_TTC>
                    <MONTANT_VENTE_TTC>123</MONTANT_VENTE_TTC>
                    <SYMB_MONNAIE/>
                    <ANNULE>0</ANNULE>
                    <CODE_TVA>123</CODE_TVA>
                    <TVA_TAUX>123</TVA_TAUX>
                    <TYPE_TICKET>123</TYPE_TICKET>
                    <POURC_REMISE/>
                    <MONTANT_REMISE/>
                </LIGNE>
```

Comment: `simplexml_load_file` does not return a string. You can't use a `str_replace` on it. You could do a `str_replace` first and then load the xml string into an object maybe.

Comment: You can't (AFAIK) `str_replace()` on a `SimpleXMLElement` (`$xml`).  You should use the original source string.  Although not sure of the purpose of the replace anyway.

Comment: @NigelRen We receiveing XML and split in into Header, Payment and Product, but XML is in the bad format and crash the rest of the code. So all what I need is the piece of code which will load XML modify it and continue using modified XML (with out saving it to the new one)

Comment: Can you show what the original XML is like and how you need to split it? There may be ways of doing it which maintain the proper XML content and doesn't need any other processing.

Comment: @NigelRen have added xml sample (this is just sample) but normally xml is broken because on the new line, not exactly here, it could be other places... that's why I would like a checker, so it could fix issues and if will be more I can update it and add an extra modifications

Comment: @NigelRen we are not making this XMLs, we just use them, so.... no way to modify them on creating stage...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a document such as...

```
<DOC>
    <LIGNE>
        <ID_TICKET>123</ID_TICKET>
        <CODE_RAYON>123</CODE_RAYON>
        <CODE_VENDEUR>123</CODE_VENDEUR>
        <PLU>123</PLU>
        <DESIGNATION_PLU>New 1234
        </DESIGNATION_PLU>
        <CODE_EAN />
        <TYPE_ARTICLE>Pièce</TYPE_ARTICLE>
        <QUANTITE_VENDUE>1</QUANTITE_VENDUE>
        <UNITE_MESURE>123</UNITE_MESURE>
        <PRIX_UNITAIRE_TTC>123</PRIX_UNITAIRE_TTC>
        <MONTANT_VENTE_TTC>123</MONTANT_VENTE_TTC>
        <SYMB_MONNAIE />
        <ANNULE>0</ANNULE>
        <CODE_TVA>123</CODE_TVA>
        <TVA_TAUX>123</TVA_TAUX>
        <TYPE_TICKET>123</TYPE_TICKET>
        <POURC_REMISE />
        <MONTANT_REMISE />
    </LIGNE>
</DOC>
```

It would be easier to update the elements using `trim()` to remove any surrounding spaces as this will cater for any other content having the same issue...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($candidateFile);
function trimXML( SimpleXMLElement $element )  {
    foreach ( $element->children() as $node )    {
        if ( $node->count() > 0 )   {
            trimXML($node);
        }
        else    {
            $node[0] = trim((string)$node);
        }
    }
}
trimXML($xml);
echo $xml->LIGNE[0]->DESIGNATION_PLU.".".PHP_EOL;
```

gives...

```
New 1234.
```

Comment: Currently, this code does not work in our circumstances, do you think it is possible to write additional checker for load->Modify-> carry on using ?? As it will be easier to understand for the future?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, once you have run `trimXML()`, then you can process `$xml` as you need to, the last `echo...` line is just an example using the test data I've put in the answer, but you need to use this with whatever processing you need.